# What is the right exponent such that $f, g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Consider the functions $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=M$, where $M$ denotes a constant. What are the right exponents $p, q$ such that $f(x)\in H^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $g(x)\in H^q(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

Moreover, there exists an exponent $r$ such that both $f(x), g(x)\in H^r(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A non-zero constant function will never by integrable over $\mathbb{R}^3$ (for Lebesgue measure), no matter the exponent. Are you sure this is the question you want to ask ?

Comment: I mean Sobolev Spaces, I edit the question.

Comment: Well $H^q(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is the space of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ functions with extra hypothesis over the weak-derivative, no ?